# Print numbers 1,2,3 using thread1 and 4,5,6 using thread2, and 7,8,9 using thread3 and again 10,11,12 using thread1

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am trying a write a simple program with wait and notify in which I will create 3 threads.

> The first thread should print 1, 2, 3.
>
> The second thread should print 4, 5, 6.
>
> The third thread should print 7, 8, 9.
>
> After that, the first thread should print 10, 11, 12 and so on.

Below is a sample code for the same exercise, but I am unable to print the desired output.

```
public class MyThread2 extends Thread {
    
    public final static Object obj = new Object();
    
    int threadNo;   
    static volatile int threadNoToRun;
    static volatile int counter = 1;
    
    public MyThread2(int threadNo){
        this.threadNo= threadNo;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (obj) {
                try {
                    if(threadNoToRun != threadNo)
                        obj.wait();
                    else{
                        for(int i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++){
                            if(threadNoToRun == threadNo){
                                System.out.println(threadNo + " counter value is "+counter);
                                counter++;
                                System.out.println(threadNo + " counter value is "+counter);
                                counter++;
                                System.out.println(threadNo + " counter value is "+counter);
                                counter++;
                                if(threadNoToRun == 1){
                                    threadNoToRun = 2;
                                }
                                else if(threadNoToRun == 2){
                                    threadNoToRun = 3;
                                }
                                else if(threadNoToRun == 3){
                                    threadNoToRun = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        obj.notifyAll();                            
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
        }    
    }
    
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    
        /*
         * Creating as many threads as needed.
         */
        MyThread2 th1 = new MyThread2(1);
        MyThread2 th2 = new MyThread2(2);
        MyThread2 th3 = new MyThread2(3);
        MyThread2.threadNoToRun = 1;
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();
    }
}
```

The output looks like:

```
1 counter value is 1
1 counter value is 2
1 counter value is 3
2 counter value is 4
2 counter value is 5
2 counter value is 6
```

Comment: I think your post has the code and output twice. Apart of that, let me look into it

Comment: Your code doesn't have any loop, therefore your threads exit after the first iteration. Thread3 happens to just go to obj.wait() and then exit the run().

Answer (score 2):

Here, it was just a few changes.

Nonetheless, I have to point out that this kind of concurrency does NOT increase computation speed. Only one thread is alive at all times.

```java
public class MyThread2 extends Thread {

    public final static Object obj = new Object();

    int threadNo;
    static volatile int threadNoToRun;
    static volatile int counter = 1;

    public MyThread2(int threadNo) {
        this.threadNo = threadNo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (obj) {
            try {
                while (counter < 100) {
                    if (threadNoToRun != threadNo)
                        obj.wait();
                    else {
                        System.out.println(threadNo + " counter value is " + counter);
                        counter++;
                        System.out.println(threadNo + " counter value is " + counter);
                        counter++;
                        System.out.println(threadNo + " counter value is " + counter);
                        counter++;
                        if (threadNoToRun == 1) {
                            threadNoToRun = 2;
                        } else if (threadNoToRun == 2) {
                            threadNoToRun = 3;
                        } else if (threadNoToRun == 3) {
                            threadNoToRun = 1;
                        }

                        obj.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /*
         * Creating as many threads as needed.
         */
        MyThread2 th1 = new MyThread2(1);
        MyThread2 th2 = new MyThread2(2);
        MyThread2 th3 = new MyThread2(3);
        MyThread2.threadNoToRun = 1;
        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th3.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `threadNoToRun+=1 % 4` to avoid the bunch of `if`s

Comment: Yah, thought about fixing that, but I didn't wanna deviate too far from OP's code :)